# Device orientation in Cocos2d-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Xcode: 7.1, running on: iPhone 6s Plus

My AppDelegate.mm has following code:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
---------some code
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
     NSLog(@"if");
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#else
          NSLog(@"else");
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#endif
---------somecode
```

My GameConfig.h has:

```
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController
```

My RootViewController.m has:

```
if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
```

My Xcode settings are:
[image]

Though device orientation goes to landscape, the game shows up still in portrait orientation. Game screenshot follows:
[image]

Comment: which cocos2d version used ?

Answer (score 1):

Add supportedInterfaceOrientations  function in RootViewController.m

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    // iPhone only
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    // iPad only
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: Added that method still same issue. cocos2d version is quite old. In cocos class headers I can see copyright 2011. I was reluctant to update it as I would hit more subtle issues.